# Using WHERE AND ||

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to a count from a table using COUNT

```
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Game_Items` WHERE `OWNER`='$player_send' && `Category`='Secondary' || `Category`='Armor'")
              or die("Get count family stored items data connect to database failled!");

    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

    $item_num = $row2[0];

if($item_num >= 1) return error;
```

This is my code, the problem is it is printing error even if it is not the case.

I was wondering is it because of the way I am using where and or together?

So I want it so that it checks that OWNER is $player_send and the category can be either secondary or armor. Have I gone about writing that the right way?

Comment: try to use sql injections

Comment: instead *||* you can use *OR*

Comment: ``AND `Category` IN ('Secondary','Armor')`` is more manageable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Game_Items` WHERE `OWNER`='$player_send' AND (`Category`='Secondary' OR `Category`='Armor')")
                      or die("Get count family stored items data connect to database failled!");
```

- Mysql doesn't support keywords `&&` and `||`. To execute AND, OR logic operators, use keywords `AND`, `OR` (incasesensitive)
- `()` is used for grouping your conditions